# React + Parse or React + Meteor?

Tags: meteor, parse-platform, web-applications, reactjs

I am trying to make a web app that let people's create website bookmarks and save their credentials for bookmarked websites, which obviously requires the app to be **secure**.

Since I am a novice in both **Parse** and **Meteor**, I am not sure which one to choose.

Second question, if I choose meteor, can I host my own back-end server rather than let meteor host for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second question: yes, you can host your own server.

To do so, use the following command to build and pack your web app:

```
meteor build {your_src_path} --architecture {os_archetecture}
```

This command will give you a node.js application, which can be easily deployed on your own server.

You can also build a docker image for your web app, which might provide you some extra convenience: [meteorhacks/meteord](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteord)

Comment: Thanks, it's good to know that! I guess it would be ok to let meteor host the app first, and then I can migrate the app to my own server later on.